# android app is not showing ads with real id

Tags: android, admob

When I am using test ID (admob_app_id and ad_unit_id), my app is showing test ads, as intended.
But with real id, there is no ad yet, inssted I am getting this message:

```
E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See ..
2020-01-28 23:38:34.625 13797-13797/com.example.phocast I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
2020-01-28 23:39:34.626 13797-13797/com.example.phocast I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
```

NB: I have created the app a couple of hours ago, but have already received the mail from google that **Great news – your account is now approved**.

what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I would give it at least 24 hours since this is a new account and a new app. Even if it says approved when I searched about this topic I got several reports of several hours to days before displaying Ads with a non testing ID